# How to take off the phone extension from a number and put it in a separate column

Tags: php, validation, explode, trim

I am currently working with an Oracle database trying to validate phone numbers within my PHP code. I have one column "PHONE 1" that contains a string phone number. This phone number may contain a leading country code "1" or a trailing phone extension (usually 4 digits). I need PHONE 1 to only contain the 10 digit phone number and then if it has country code or extension, I need to remove them and store them in separate columns which are currently empty within my Oracle database ("PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE" and "PHONE 1 EXTENSION"). I have found a way to remove the leading country code, but I am not sure how to remove the trailing extension. I looked into possibly using the explode() function but cannot figure it out. Here is my code that I am using to remove the leading 1:

```
while($row=oci_fetch_array($array, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
    //VALIDATE PHONE NUMBERS AND COUNTRY CODES
    if(isset($row["PHONE 1"])){
        if (strlen($row["PHONE 1"])>10){
            $row["PHONE 1"] = preg_replace("/^1/", '',$row["PHONE 1"]);
            $row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"]="1";
            if(strlen($row["PHONE 1"])>10){
            //insert code here that will remove the extension and add it to the column $row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"]
            }

        }
        }
```

I think that using adding the second if statement within the other will be the easiest way to remove the extension. Essentially, this should say if there are more than 10 digits, remove the leading 1, and then if there are still more than 10 digits, remove the trailing extension. I just need to figure out how to code the latter. Any input on how to improve my current code or add the new one will be appreciated.

Comment: How consistent is the data? if they're all exactly the same format, then you could use `explode` or even `substr` to parse the phone numbers. If not, you'll have to get more creative and/or divide the numbers up into groups with the same format - try regular expressions.

Comment: It is not very consistent at all. Sometimes it will be a valid 10 digit number, but other times at worst will be something like 1800496333244170 (sometimes even 18004964321ext12345 but I wont worry about those just yet). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How you handle the phone numbers varies, depending on what you're starting with and what you want to end up with.

A good strategy for this type of problem is to "divide & conquer".

Divide your data into two groups - for example, those with extensions & those without.

Take the ones with extensions and divide them further, say into groups like "8005551212x100" (ie. with an 'x' denoting the extension) and others. Now you know how to handle the first group - split the string on the 'x', put the phone number into one column in your database and the extension into another. Now you have a few more phone numbers (with a variety formats, probably), but the extensions have been taken care of.

Methods for handling the phone numbers include:

1. `explode` - good for separating strings with clearly defined delimiters. Eg. `explode("x", "8005551212x100") == array("8005551212", "100")`
2. `substr` - good for strings where specific information appears at specific locations in the string. Eg. `substr("8005551212",3,3) == "555"`
3. regular expressions - can be good for variable data. Eg. for phone numbers where the extension is delimited by "x" or "ext" or "extension": `preg_match("/^[0-9]+(x|ext|extension)[0-9]+$/", "8005551212ext100")`. Be careful, though, to resist the temptation to write one regular expression that covers ALL types of numbers in your database - it's probably possible, but you're drive yourself crazy trying to write & debug an insanely long regular expression. That's why I suggest dividing your data up into groups of similar formats.

Comment: Ok thanks, but to be honest the numbers with an "x" or "extension" are in the vast minority. I really just need to figure out how to handle numbers like 800123123499968. The only issue with using a substr() function is that all of the numbers do not share the same leading number before the extension. (Ie. there may be a 8001234567 and then a 8007654321). How would I handle those?

Comment: I've described three methods for parsing the strings above - you're going to have to decide (on a case by case basis perhaps - you're probably going to spend a lot of time examining the data) which is best for a given phone number format. That's why I suggested dividing them up into groups of similar format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using this if statement and it did the trick. 
if(strlen($row["PHONE 1"])>10){
    $extension=substr($row["PHONE 1"],10);
    $row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"]=$extension;
    $row["PHONE 1"]=substr($row["PHONE 1"],0,10);
    }